# How to use array contains in 2 different fields or is there an alternative query?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want filter languages and id, but I can't use it because it is in different fields. What can i do differently to allow this use-case?

eg. my values:

```
languages = ["English","Türkçe"]
passedUserIds = ["asasd123123","12312asd12dsa"]
smashedUserIds = ["abcvb123123","1231cvb12dsa"]
```

> **Limitations**: Note the following limitations for != queries: Only documents where the given field exists can match the query. You can't combine not-in and != in a compound query. In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

and second:

> **Limitations**: Note the following limitations for in, not-in, and array-contains-any: in, not-in, and array-contains-any support up to 10 comparison values. You can use at most one array-contains clause per query. You can't combine array-contains with array-contains-any. You can use at most one in, not-in, or array-contains-any clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query. You can't combine not-in with not equals !=. You can't order your query by a field included in an equality (==) or in clause.

And my firestore model:

```
collections     
matches     
passes      
smashes     
users     
     =>documents    
             ids eg         
         1234214asdf12          
          1231212abd              
               => fields              
                     gender                    
                  "Female"                     
                      id              
                        "1231212abd"         
                      languages                  
                       0                   
                    "中文"                
                        1                
                      "عربي"                
                          2                  
                   "Deutsch"
```

My code:

```
 unlanguages = firestore().collection("users")
.where("languages", "array-contains-any", languages)
.where("id", "not-in", [...passedUserIds, ...smashesUserIds]) .onSnapshot(querySnapshot =>{  
if (querySnapshot?.docs?.length > 0) {    
    setProfiles(querySnapshot?.docs.filter((doc) => doc.id != user.uid)
    .filter((doc) => doc._data.gender != loggedInProfile.gender)
    .filter((doc) => doc._data.age <= ${value[1]})
    .filter((doc) => doc._data.age >= ${value[0]}) 
    .map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })))
    setActiveLoad(false);     
    } else {
    setActiveLoad(false);
    }
    })    
    return unlanguages
```

and i tried many things in the

```
setProfiles(querySnapshot?.docs .filter((doc) => doc.id != user.uid)    
=> .filter((doc) => doc.id != passedUserIds)    
=> .filter((doc) => doc.id != smashesUserIds)    
 .filter((doc) => doc._data.gender != loggedInProfile.gender)   
 .filter((doc) => doc._data.age <= ${value[1]})    
 .filter((doc) => doc._data.age >= ${value[0]})    
 .map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })))
```

I added but not working and if I use just like this

passedUserIds[0]

yes its working but only 1 value. so It's could be 1000 maybe 10000 value, I do not know what to do?

Comment: how does it look now? I'm learning stack overflow new new

Comment: how does it look now?

Comment: Much better! Thanks; 
Cleaning up comments...

Comment: This time I added the languages ​​to the filter field, but I still couldn't get out of it, is there still no solution?
.filter((doc) => doc._data.languages[0] && doc._data.languages[0] === languages[0] ? languages[0] : languages[1] ? languages[1] : languages[2] ? languages[2] : languages[3] ? languages[3] : languages[4] ? languages[4] : languages[5] ? languages[5] : languages[6] ? languages[6] : languages[7] ? languages[7] : false)
                        .filter((doc) => doc._data.languages[1] && doc._data.languages[1]

Comment: Now it doesn't work when I select 1 language, it works when I select 2 - 5 languages, but if I select all languages, it doesn't work
codes
.filter((doc) => doc._data.languages.sort()[0] &&
                            doc._data.languages.sort()[0] == languages.sort()[0] ||
                            doc._data.languages.sort()[0] == languages.sort()[1] ||
                            doc._data.languages.sort()[0] == languages.sort()[2] ||
                            doc._data.languages.sort()[0] == languages.sort()[3] ||
                         etc. 
.
.
.

Comment: and .filter((doc) => doc._data.languages.sort()[1] &&
                            doc._data.languages.sort()[1] == languages.sort()[0] ||
                            doc._data.languages.sort()[1] == languages.sort()[1] ||
                            doc._data.languages.sort()[1] == languages.sort()[2] ||
codes just like this and keep going

Comment: and return doc_data.languages.sort() => eg.  LOG  doc._data.languages.sort()) ["Other", "عربي", "中文"]
 LOG  doc._data.languages.sort()) ["English", "Türkçe"]
and return languages => languages ["Deutsch", "English", "Español", "Other", "Türkçe", "Русский", "中文", "عربي"]

Comment: and return users languages all options if users 1 languages English Türkçe and if you choose filter languages English Türkçe its working only for it but if I select 1 language from filter but not working, its filter code return "and option"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved it like this, i gave the opportunity to choose only 1 language while filtering, dropdownpicker, I set multiple false, and its working

and last filter codes

```
.where("id", "not-in", [...passedUserIds, ...smashesUserIds])
        .onSnapshot(async querySnapshot => {
            if (querySnapshot?.docs?.length > 0) {
                setActiveLoad(true)
                let dondur2 = await querySnapshot?.docs
                    .filter((doc) => doc.id != user.uid)
                    .filter((doc) => doc._data.gender != loggedInProfile.gender)
                    .filter((doc) => doc._data.age <= `${value[1]}`)
                    .filter((doc) => doc._data.age >= `${value[0]}`)
                    .filter((doc) =>
                        doc._data.languages[0] == languages ||
                        doc._data.languages[1] == languages ||
                        doc._data.languages[2] == languages ||
                        doc._data.languages[3] == languages ||
                        doc._data.languages[4] == languages ||
                        doc._data.languages[5] == languages ||
                        doc._data.languages[6] == languages ||
                        doc._data.languages[7] == languages
                    )
                    .map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
```